# Asp.net Return View returns with checkbox checked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project where I report time. I have a Checkbox "No Time To Report" I check that and it will disable all the fields. Because if you do not have something to report you do not need too enter hours and so on.

However, after submitting my time report, on the returned view, that checkbox will be checked. I want it to be unchecked when I return to my view again. If I refresh the page the checkbox will be unchecked by default.

I return my view like this:
`return View();` I assume that would be the same as a refresh?

First report:
[image]

but as I get returned to the same view the checkbox is still checked:
[image]

Doing a refresh fixes it and the checkbox will be false. But there have to be an easier way to get this working instead of refreshing the page?

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult TimeReport(FormCollection form, Guid? id, bool? noTimeToReport)
    {
        ShowProjects(true);

        NewTimeReportModel projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();

        //Deletes Timereport
        if (form != null && form.AllKeys.Contains("delete"))
        {
            new DatabaseLayer().DeleteTimeReport(Guid.Parse(form["ReportId"]));
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
            ViewData.Model = projectData;
            ViewData["deleted"] = true;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //Update Timereport
        if (id.HasValue && (form == null || form.AllKeys.Length == 0))
        {
            using (DatabaseLayer db = new DatabaseLayer())
            {
                var timeReport = db.GetTimeReport(id.Value);
                projectData = new NewTimeReportModel(timeReport);
            }
        }
        //Loads default settings
        else if (form == null || form.AllKeys.Length == 0)
        {
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
        }
        else
        {
            //Get's all the dates from the view and formates them to look like yy-mm-dd so we can parse it to a datetime.
            List<string> dates = FormateDate(form["date"]);
            //Loops over all the dates and saves the dates to the database.
            projectData = ReportDates(form, projectData, dates, noTimeToReport);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //If we get this far everything is ok and we save the timereport to the database
                projectData.SaveToDatabase(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
                ViewData["posted"] = true;
                projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
            }
            else if (projectData.Projects.Count == 1)
            {
                ListAllMssingDays();
                ViewData.Model = projectData;
                return View(projectData);
            }

            //Loads default settings if all dates been reported.
            LoadDefaultSettings(projectData);
        }
        //Get's and lists all the missing days
        ListAllMssingDays();
        return View();
    }
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="test12">
                    <div class="tabbable tabbable-custom tabbable-noborder tabbable-reversed">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="portlet light bordered">
                                <div class="portlet-title">
                                    <div class="caption">
                                        <span class="caption-subject font-green-sharp bold uppercase">Rapportera tid</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="portlet-body form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-5">Ingen tid att rapportera</label>
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NoTimeToReport, new { @id = "check" })
                                    </div>
                                    @if (Model.ReportId.HasValue)
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Redigera datum:</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                @Html.TextBox("date", Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Start tid:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Slut tid:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Rast Längd:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tid jobbad:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-5">
                                            @Html.TextBox("workedHours", Model.Times.WorkedHours, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a view model instead?

Comment: can you post the razor, in particular, the part that renders the check box ?

Comment: @FabioSalvalai Done. Updated my question.

Comment: @Canvas What do you mean? Insted of returning a view, I return the model?

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson In your controller, pass an empty model in, then you can make sure your bool variable is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Does the problem happen when your model is valid?

I noticed you instantiate

```
projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
```

but you never use it afterwards. Perhaps `ViewData.Model` was set before with another, outdated instance.

You should check that the model you are passing is in the state you expect.

**Edit:**

Also,

> I return my view like this: return View(); I assume that would be the same as a refresh?

Answer is no: it returns a page with a brand new state. The state you give to your page is the one you pass as a model. Either as a parameter to `View()` or by setting `ViewData.Model`

Comment: I need my ViewData.Model there or my view will crash due Object reference not set to an instance of an object. how ever that projectData holds NoTimeToReport = false and even if I return that it will set the checkbox to checked.

Comment: And I load my settings: LoadDefaultSettings(projectData); NoTimeToReport is also set to false there. Yet it still is checked on my view after returning.

Comment: I don't have the detail of `LoadDefaultSettings` does it set the view model ? it seems when `return View();` is hit, `model.NoTimeToReport` is set to `true`, that's why I ask.

Comment: You are correct when it hits return view, model.NoTimeToReport is set to true. I believe I know how to solve that.. Maybe

Comment: It seems to me you should add `ViewData.Model = projectData;` after calling LoadDefaultSettings(projectData); (Here, I'm assuming there is no reason to load these details if you don't juse them.)

Comment: I do use LoadDefaultSettings it is the my time settings so I do not have to enter a start date / end date if I work same hours everyday

Comment: yes, I understood that. you call `LoadDefaultSettings` indeed. And it will modify the `projectData` you pass to it. this is true as well. Your problem is that after `projectData` is modified, it is not used anymore. In some cases it will work because you already assigned `projectData` to be the view model, but sometimes: you create a brand new instance, you modify that instance, and you do nothing with it. i.e. when your model is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the programming style you adopted is not helping you see things clearly.

The model you use for your view has the property `NoTimeToReport` set to `true` instead of `false`. Now, to find why, this is going to be complicated with your code, because your model is instantiated more than once, its values are set at multiple places, and the object is set as the model more than once, using `ViewData.Model = projectData;`

Instead, the recommended way would be to :

- Instanciate your model *only once*
- Set all its properties as you see fit
- *Never* set the ViewData.Model property
- Pass your model to the `View()` method as follows:

  ```
  return View(projectData);
  ```

That way, you will be able to see *where* you are setting one of its property with the wrong value, and you will be sure that the right instance of the model is used when displaying the view.

Comment: But even if I pass in projectData with noTimeToReport  set to false it will still have the check box enabled when going on my view.

Comment: Does it? If it does,  perhaps you are still setting ViewData.Model somewhere before and it takes precedence over the provided model.

Comment: It would seem like that, setting over return View NoTimeToReport is set to True

Comment: did you remove *all* the assignations to `ViewData.Model` as specified in the answer?

Comment: I can't if I do that my view will crash.

Comment: Not if you pass it as an argument to View(...). Have you even tried it?

Comment: Just passing in projectData in my view? Yes. It doesn't crash than but even though projectData holds false, the return still says True.

Comment: can you create a gist (https://gist.github.com/) of your `TimeReport` method after modification ?

Comment: I commented your gist. I believe you didn't properly read my answer, please take your time and read it through.

Comment: Though the Return in the view I still want there, because if the model is not valid I do not want to have to enter all the information again.

Comment: what line, 49? In that case, OK, but make sure `NoTimeToReport` is set correctly then.

Comment: Even though I do hard code the value to be false noTimeToReport = false; Stepping over my Return View(); it says it will return noTimetoReport False... but it stil checked.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the razor on `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.NoTimeToReport, new { @id = "check" })` and see the value there. Is it true or false ?

Comment: It seems to be false.

Comment: I am confused, Joakim. 5 hours ago, you said _You are correct when it hits return view, model.NoTimeToReport is set to true._

Comment: I harded coded it so before it returns the view I set the noTimeToReport = false, than in my view on my checkbox the value is False. but when the view loads up the checkbox is checked.

Comment: lets move this discussion to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90881/discussion-between-fabio-salvalai-and-joakim-carlsson